# How to use OrderByValue in Unity

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort the rooms based on their `type`. How do I get the room which has the `"type" = "triple"`? I am using Unity3d.

[image]

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
.GetReference("rooms").OrderByChild("type").EqualTo("triple")
.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
}
```

EDIT: I have got the Rooms part. But now, how can I get the keys i.e only the room number?

Comment: Please post code instead of image.

Comment: Code is what I want. I am sorry but the documentation wasn't enough. I was able to retrieve data without sorting but I am not able to retrieve the sorted data. Still I'll try to upload the one. Thank you for your reply. Hope to get another one.

Comment: We need a some code to modify it so please add relevant code that you done so far in your question

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not ordering/filtering by value, but ordering by a child property.

So you'll need to use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .GetReference("rooms").OrderByChild("type").EqualTo("triple")
    .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
}
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#sort_data).

Comment: Here I want to get the room number (only the room number) for the type "triple". However, I am not able to do that.

args.Snapshot.Child("rooms")